# jQuery: slimScrollbar hides elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use: http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/ 
(Scroll down to see typical examples)

This is my codepen:
http://codepen.io/jzhang172/pen/admvRR

```js
$(function(){
    $('#container').slimScroll({
        height: '250px'
    });
});
```

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed");

    *{
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html{
     background: url('img/congruent_pentagon.png');
    }

    body{

    margin:0px;
    }
    #wrapper{
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 300px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-top: 2em;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
        height: 100%;
        font: 25px/24px normal 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
        background: transparent;
    }

    a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .social{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        margin-right: 16px;
        background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 0.6);
        box-shadow: 8px 8px 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }

    nav{
     padding-top: 8px;
     padding-left: 8px;
     padding-right: 8px;
 }

 nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

nav ul li a.email{
 border-left: 50px solid #c9182c;
 color: #c9182c;
}

nav ul li a.twitter{
    border-left: 50px solid #00a0d1;
    color: #00a0d1;
}

nav ul li a.facebook{
    border-left: 50px solid #365998;
    color: #365998;
}

nav ul li a.github{
    border-left: 50px solid #4183c4;
    color: #4183c4;
}

nav ul li a.google{
    border-left: 50px solid #db4a39;
    color: #db4a39;
}

nav ul li a.instagram{
    border-left: 50px solid #634d40;
    color: #634d40;
}

nav ul li a.tumblr{
    border-left: 50px solid #34526f;
    color: #34526f;
}

nav ul li a.scriptogram{
 border-left: 50px solid #0088cc;
 color: #0088cc;
}
nav ul li a.linkedin{
    border-left: 50px solid #0e76a8;
    color: #0e76a8;
}

.container{
    width:100%;
    
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
    padding-top:20px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;

    
}
.container h1{
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-size:55px;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;

}
.container span{
    width:100px;
    height:300px;;
}
h2{
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25px;f
    font-weight:normal;

}
#headline{
    font-size:10px;
}

span img{
        height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: -20px;

}

.announcements{
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:500px;
    min-height:500px;
    background:rgba(152, 170, 179, 0.44);
    border:1px solid #B1F6CB;
    border-radius:20px;
    padding-top:10px;
}
.announcements h2{
font-size:20px;
font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
font-weight:800;
float:left;
background:#0B437D;
width:100%;
color:#F9F9F9;;
}

span.date{
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
}
span.important{
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:800px;
    
    color:red;
}

.sectionwrapper{
    width:100%;
    padding:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:390px;
       overflow:auto;
       padding-top:0px;
       position:relative;

}

span.new-policy{
    background:#2184BF;
    color:#F3F3F3;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

span.description{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

.section a{
    color:black;
}
.section a:hover{
color:#23A6D0;
transition:.1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-slimScroll/1.3.7/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville|Lora|Maven+Pro|Merriweather|EB+Garamond|Open+Sans|Lato|Slabo+27px|Josefin+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="announcements">
  <h2>Announcements</h2>
  <div class="sectionwrapper" id="container">
  <div class="section">
    <span class="date">12/20/15</span><br><span class="important">!</span>
    <span class="new-policy"> New Policy </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="description">&nbsp;&nbsp;Paid Week Time Off each Month  <br>Every month, choose any week for paid time off for that entire week.  Spend time with your loved ones.  Go travel som...</span></a>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="section">
        <span class="date">12/27/15</span><br><span class="important">!</span>
    <span class="new-policy"> New Policy </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="description">&nbsp;&nbsp;Paid Week Time Off each Month  <br>Every month, choose any week for paid time off for that entire week.  Spend time with your loved ones.  Go travel som...</span></a>
  </div>
  <hr>


  <div class="section">
        <span class="date">12/20/15</span><br><span class="important">!</span>
    <span class="new-policy"> New Policy </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="description">&nbsp;&nbsp;Paid Week Time Off each Month  <br>Every month, choose any week for paid time off for that entire week.  Spend time with your loved ones.  Go travel som...</span></a>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <div class="section">
            <span class="date">12/20/15</span><br><span class="important">!</span>
    <span class="new-policy"> New Policy </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="description">&nbsp;&nbsp;Paid Week Time Off each Month  <br>Every month, choose any week for paid time off for that entire week.  Spend time with your loved ones.  Go travel som...</span></a>
  </div>
  <hr>
    <div class="section">
            <span class="date">12/20/15</span><br><span class="important">!</span>
    <span class="new-policy"> New Policy </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="description">&nbsp;&nbsp;Paid Week Time Off each Month  <br>Every month, choose any week for paid time off for that entire week.  Spend time with your loved ones.  Go travel som...</span></a>
  </div>
  <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you remove the JS, it shows everything in the box.  Why is it doing that?  Why isn't the Jquery plugin working?

Comment: Are you aware about the fact that you are loading slimscroll before Jquery?

Comment: Now jQuery is before slimscroll. Before my edit there were actually 2 references to each (2 slimscroll and 2 jquery). But the problem was unrelated to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ccs `float: left` in the `.announcements h2` seems to be triggering the problem. I removed that and it worked.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#container').slimScroll({
        height: '250px'
    });
});
```

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed");

    *{
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html{
     background: url('img/congruent_pentagon.png');
    }

    body{

    margin:0px;
    }
    #wrapper{
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 300px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-top: 2em;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
        height: 100%;
        font: 25px/24px normal 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
        background: transparent;
    }

    a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .social{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        margin-right: 16px;
        background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 0.6);
        box-shadow: 8px 8px 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }

    nav{
     padding-top: 8px;
     padding-left: 8px;
     padding-right: 8px;
 }

 nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

nav ul li a.email{
 border-left: 50px solid #c9182c;
 color: #c9182c;
}

nav ul li a.twitter{
    border-left: 50px solid #00a0d1;
    color: #00a0d1;
}

nav ul li a.facebook{
    border-left: 50px solid #365998;
    color: #365998;
}

nav ul li a.github{
    border-left: 50px solid #4183c4;
    color: #4183c4;
}

nav ul li a.google{
    border-left: 50px solid #db4a39;
    color: #db4a39;
}

nav ul li a.instagram{
    border-left: 50px solid #634d40;
    color: #634d40;
}

nav ul li a.tumblr{
    border-left: 50px solid #34526f;
    color: #34526f;
}

nav ul li a.scriptogram{
 border-left: 50px solid #0088cc;
 color: #0088cc;
}
nav ul li a.linkedin{
    border-left: 50px solid #0e76a8;
    color: #0e76a8;
}

.container{
    width:100%;
    
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
    padding-top:20px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;

    
}
.container h1{
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-size:55px;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;

}
.container span{
    width:100px;
    height:300px;;
}
h2{
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25px;f
    font-weight:normal;

}
#headline{
    font-size:10px;
}

span img{
        height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: -20px;

}

.announcements{
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:500px;
    min-height:500px;
    background:rgba(152, 170, 179, 0.44);
    border:1px solid #B1F6CB;
    border-radius:20px;
    padding-top:10px;
}
.announcements h2{
font-size:20px;
font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
font-weight:800;
/*float:left;*/
background:#0B437D;
width:100%;
color:#F9F9F9;;
}

span.date{
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
}
span.important{
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:800px;
    
    color:red;
}

.sectionwrapper{
    width:100%;
    padding:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:390px;
       overflow:auto;
       padding-top:0px;
       position:relative;

}

span.new-policy{
    background:#2184BF;
    color:#F3F3F3;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

span.description{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

.section a{
    color:black;
}
.section a:hover{
color:#23A6D0;
transition:.1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-slimScroll/1.3.7/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville|Lora|Maven+Pro|Merriweather|EB+Garamond|Open+Sans|Lato|Slabo+27px|Josefin+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='img/favicon.ico' type='img/favicon.ico'>
<div class="announcements">
  <h2>Announcements</h2>
  <div class="sectionwrapper" id="container">
  <div class="section">
    <span class="date">12/20/15</span><br><span class="important">!</span>
    <span class="new-policy"> New Policy </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="description">&nbsp;&nbsp;Paid Week Time Off each Month  <br>Every month, choose any week for paid time off for that entire week.  Spend time with your loved ones.  Go travel som...</span></a>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="section">
        <span class="date">12/27/15</span><br><span class="important">!</span>
    <span class="new-policy"> New Policy </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="description">&nbsp;&nbsp;Paid Week Time Off each Month  <br>Every month, choose any week for paid time off for that entire week.  Spend time with your loved ones.  Go travel som...</span></a>
  </div>
  <hr>


  <div class="section">
        <span class="date">12/20/15</span><br><span class="important">!</span>
    <span class="new-policy"> New Policy </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="description">&nbsp;&nbsp;Paid Week Time Off each Month  <br>Every month, choose any week for paid time off for that entire week.  Spend time with your loved ones.  Go travel som...</span></a>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <div class="section">
            <span class="date">12/20/15</span><br><span class="important">!</span>
    <span class="new-policy"> New Policy </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="description">&nbsp;&nbsp;Paid Week Time Off each Month  <br>Every month, choose any week for paid time off for that entire week.  Spend time with your loved ones.  Go travel som...</span></a>
  </div>
  <hr>
    <div class="section">
            <span class="date">12/20/15</span><br><span class="important">!</span>
    <span class="new-policy"> New Policy </span>
    <a href="#"><span class="description">&nbsp;&nbsp;Paid Week Time Off each Month  <br>Every month, choose any week for paid time off for that entire week.  Spend time with your loved ones.  Go travel som...</span></a>
  </div>
  <hr>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  You know that feeling when your head has been in code all day long and you don't know what to do but a simple change like that can fix it...saved me a headache :p

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css file and it works fine.

```
.slimScrollDiv {
  overflow: visible!important;
}
```

It's just one of their css setting which probably doesn't fit your page.

Comment: thankyouuuuuu, I chose to remove float:left, just because it was easier and I didn't need that piece to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I use SlimScroll and really like it.

There is an issue with your H2 Tag Below. Remove or comment this out and SlimScroll will show.

```
 <h2>Announcements</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm amazed at how something like that made it work